# May DWS calling functions from sample unit?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

May DWS calling functions from sample unit? For example:

```
FExecution.Info.Func['Test.ClickProc'].Call(AParams); (This is not working)
```

FExecution - IdwsProgramExecution;

Function declared in Script code:

```
unit Test;
Uses UTestUnit;
procedure TestFunc(LParam: string);
begin
  ShowMessage(LParam);
end;
procedure ClickProc(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('DWS');
end;
var  S: TStringList;
var  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := TButton.Create(MainForm);
  btn.OnClick := ClickProc;
  btn.Parent(MainForm);
end.
```

ClickProc in this example.

Comment: Is the answer to [How to declare a method of a Delphi object called from a script having a procedure type argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33253042/576719) what you are looking for?

Comment: No. In this answer Graymatter calling only by function name. I need call by unit name and function. And I forget, sorry, function declared in script code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done.

The symbol lookup in the call to `Info.Func[]` doesn't resolve the name into a unit scope and an identifier but instead does a simple lookup for a symbol named "Test.ClickProc". However since the `ClickProc` procedure symbol is named "ClickProc" the lookup doesn't find it.

I thought that maybe it would be possible to find the procedure symbol manually via the symbol tables...

```
var
  FExecution: IdwsProgramExecution;
  UnitSymbol: TUnitMainSymbol;
  FuncSymbol: TFuncSymbol;
  Info: IInfo;
begin
  ...
  UnitSymbol := FExecution.Prog.UnitMains.Find('Test');
  FuncSymbol := UnitSymbol.Table.FindSymbol('ClickProc', cvPublic) as TFuncSymbol; // Returns nil :-(
  Info := FExecution.Info.FuncBySym[FuncSymbol];
  Info.Call;
  ...
```

... but after consulting the "documentation" (*read: studying the source, stepping through with a debugger and much trial and error*) I've come to the conclusion that it cannot be done reliably at this time. It *is* possible to find the "ClickProc" symbol in one of the many symbol tables but I've not been able to find a reliable way to qualify the symbol with a unit name/symbol.